# Matploblib: Paint cells of matrix based on indexes stored in array

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

I' built a matrix with Numpy and set values to the matrix cells, and plotted it with Matplotlib in the code below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


matrix = np.loadtxt('C:\folder/matrix_values.txt', usecols=range(20))  
matrix = np.int8(matriz)


fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.matshow(matrix, origin='upper', alpha=0, cmap=None, interpolation='nearest')

for i in xrange(20):
    for j in xrange(20):
        value = matrix[j,i]
        ax1.text(i, j, str(value), va='center', ha='center')


tick_labels = range(20)
ax1.set_xticks([], minor=False)
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, 20, 1), minor=True)
ax1.set_yticks([], minor=False)
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, 20, 1), minor=True)
ax1.set_xticklabels([], minor=False)
ax1.set_xticklabels(tick_labels, minor=True)
ax1.set_yticklabels([], minor=False)
ax1.set_yticklabels(tick_labels, minor=True)
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax1.grid(which='minor', color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Now I have an array with some of the matrix cells's coordinates, like [[0,1],[0,0],[0,2]...]. That array is generated randomly, at each time I run the code, I have for example 12 cells' coordinates alocated in the array, at another time it might be 17 etc. It's a 20x20 matrix, with 400 cells. How could I paint the background of the cells indicated in the array of coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may first create an array of the same shape as the original matrix and fill it with zeros. Then, at the positions defined by the coordinate array, put ones into that array. Finally plot that array, instead of the original matrix.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


matrix = np.random.randint(0,9, size=(10,10))
highlight = np.array([[1,3],[4,2],[6,8],[7,2]])

hm = np.zeros_like(matrix)
hm[highlight[:,1],highlight[:,0]] = 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.matshow(hm, origin='upper', alpha=1, vmin=0, vmax=2, cmap="Blues")

for i in range(matrix.shape[1]):
    for j in range(matrix.shape[1]):
        ax.text(i, j, str(matrix[j,i]), va='center', ha='center')

n = min(matrix.shape)+1
tick_labels = range(n)
ax.set_xticks([], minor=False)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, n-1, 1), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks([], minor=False)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, n-1, 1), minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels([], minor=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(tick_labels, minor=True)
ax.set_yticklabels([], minor=False)
ax.set_yticklabels(tick_labels, minor=True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.grid(which='minor', color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]